# Control MapboxGL geometry simplification

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

MapboxGL does some levels of feature simplification &/or filtering depending on zoom level (for performance reasons.)

I am rendering full-coverage data as vector tiles (Canada census data in this case.) When polygons are simplified or filtered based on zoom, this causes holes to be visible in a dataset that should be continuous.

I have some control over simplification on the server, but I have limited server-side simplification already, for the same reason. When viewing these same tiles with [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) or [Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile) in leaflet, the tiles show up fine at all zoom levels.

Is it possible to override client side simplification thresholds?

[image: differences at zoom levels 8-11]

Answer (score 3):

Vector tile sources are not simplified or modified clientside. Any simplification must be done on the server.

GeoJSON sources are simplified clientside and can be configured with the [`tolerance` property](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-geojson-tolerance)

Comment: Strange that the same tiles display without holes in the other 2 libs...